# JavaScript array object oscillates emptiness

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I'm working on a site that draws in a canvas.
In order to work with animations, the canvas redraws itself every 40 ms, essentially 25 fps.

The refresh re-draws all of the canvas elements which are stored in `this.elements`, an array initialized as empty.

Elements are added to `this.elements` with `this.elements.push(elem)`.

The redraw timer is set with the following (mixing in constants):

```
setInterval(function(){
    redraw();
}, 40);
```

`redraw()` does the following:

```
redraw = function () {
    var ctx = this.getContext(); // canvas element with 2d graphics context
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    for(var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++){
        // draw the element
    }
}
```

Drawing works as intended—the issue is that `this.elements` oscillates between containing all of the elements and being empty—specifically 1 of the former followed by 2 of the latter.

Putting a `console.log(this.elements.length)` in the `redraw()` function gives the following output when there are 54 elements added to the canvas:

[image: log output]

This oscillation sometimes produces a strobing effect in the canvas.

What is causing the array to oscillate between emptiness?

Comment: Did you bind that `redraw` to any other object?

Comment: how are elements accessed from the `elements` array?

Comment: @fuyushimoya: no, `redraw` is only ever called from that one timer.

@lemieuxster: basically `this.elements[i].draw();`, where `draw` is a method of the elems that handles actually drawing on the canvas.

Comment: Then the `this` you use here is very ambiguous, it probably points to some other thing you didn't expect, you can `console.log(this)` to see the result.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can use `setInterval(redraw, 40)`, without anonymous functions.

Comment: @fuyushimoya: Thanks—I think I've found the bug. `this` is the graphics module I'm using but I pinpointed that there are multiple instances of the same module all drawing on the same canvas.

Answer (score 0):

There were three instances of the same graphics module all drawing on the same canvas. As `elements` was different across the three, the canvas was strobing.